# Find the inverse matrix as a function of M

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let the polynomial $p(x)=a_0+a_1 x+\dots+a_nx^n$, with $a_0\neq 0$. Let M be an invertible matrix and suppose $p(M)=0$. Find a invertible matrix $M^{-1}$ as a function of M.

**How I try:** $p(M)=a_0I+a_1 M+ a_2 M^2+ \dots + a_n M^n = a_0 M M^{-1}+a_1 M+ a_2 M^2+ \dots + a_n M^n$

$\Rightarrow M(a_0 M^{-1}+a_1  I + \dots + a_n M^{n-1})=0$

But in this way I find $M^{-1}$ as a function of the coefficients of the polynomial $p(x)$.

I think I'm thinking the wrong way.

Comment: Not at all. What you did is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the wording of the question.... If we are not completely sure there is an inverse, but we have $p(M)=a_0I+a_1 M+ a_2 M^2+ \dots + a_n M^n $ with $a_0 \neq 0$ and the value $p(M) = 0$ as a matrix, we have
$$ a_1 M+ a_2 M^2+ \dots + a_n M^n = - a_0I. $$  Then
$$ -\frac{a_1}{a_0} M  -\frac{a_2}{a_0} M^2+ \dots  -\frac{a_n}{a_0} M^n = I, $$
 $$ M \left(-\frac{a_1}{a_0} I  -\frac{a_2}{a_0} M+ \dots  -\frac{a_n}{a_0} M^{n-1} \right) = I. $$
We could instead have written, either way it is just the distributive  law,
 $$  \left(-\frac{a_1}{a_0} I  -\frac{a_2}{a_0} M+ \dots  -\frac{a_n}{a_0} M^{n-1} \right) M = I. $$
It is this expression that says that $M$ has an inverse, and the inverse is equal to
 $$  \left(-\frac{a_1}{a_0} I  -\frac{a_2}{a_0} M+ \dots  -\frac{a_n}{a_0} M^{n-1} \right)  $$